# Intercept click on content in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, ads

I have an `iframe` that references an external URL that serves up pages that contain Flash adverts.

I need to track how often a customer clicks on one of those adverts.

The approach I am taking is to render a `div` element over the `iframe`. This allows me to intercept the click event, however I need to pass that click down to the `iframe`. Is this possible using JavaScript?

Comment: Clever idea. But passing them down will probably be impossible.

Comment: How are you intercepting the click with the div element? My clicks are not being intercepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  You can't simulate a *real* click in javascript, you can only fire *click* events.

Comment: And even if one could, it would not work because of Cross Domain Policy.

Comment: Is there a way to intercept the redirect event/request? in case the iframe redirects to another page, is there a way to listen for that?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that it is possible as well

But, assuming that the clicks redirect the user to the site of the advert, you could intercept the user click using redirections. Change the link to some script on your own server with some unique advert id. Register the click and redirect the user to the advertisement page.

Another possibility is to use this technique to load the contents of the iframe, so you known the amount of customers viewed the advertisement. But this of course might be an advertisement scheme your advertisement customer does not like/want.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but how can one intercept the redirect without using the click event (since that won't work with the iframe and external domain)?

Comment: Lets say advertisement click goes to URL_AD, you replace this to go to your script/server URL_ME and then use a redirect to URL_AD from the script. You you get click->URL_ME (register click) -> URL_AD. Might not be ideal, but at least you would be able to register clicking the ads

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the click through by any legitimate means, and you'll run up against cross-domain problems if you tried to fake it in anyway. And I would definitely stay away from anything that looks like a [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) solution - it's bound to stop working (and feels evil too).

You may be able to hack something, depending on how accurate it has to be. This would involve tracking the sequence of events happening when user has put their mouse into the banner area and then left the page (inferring that they clicked on the ad). You'll miss some, and you may catch some false positives too.

It would work something like:

1. Leave the covering div in place
2. onMouseOver, hide the div and set an
   onbeforeunload event handler that
   registers a "click" through an AJAX post (or similar)
3. when the mouse moves out of the banner area it means they didn't click the ad, so show the div again and remove the event handler

I'd guesstimate you'd get about 80-90% accuracy, but you're going to have to test on a lot of browsers. It's also assuming the ad loads into the same window and not a new one. If it loads into a new one then I think it's going to be even harder.