# How to click a button with no id or name, inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, iframe, click

I need to click the button (without an id and name) inside an iframe (with an id and name) with using JavaScript/jQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name="abb" id="abb" src="http://example.com" scrolling="no"frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:45px; left:-19px; height:21px; z-index: 0; position: relative;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("abb").contentWindow.document.getElementsByName('REG_BTN')[0].click();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intercept click on content in an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085752/intercept-click-on-content-in-an-iframe)

Answer (score 3):

You can't access the DOM of documents on other origins.

The closest you could come would be to [send a message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to the document which would have to include JS that listened for the message and responded accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you could always traverse it by using id or name of the tag that you do know

for example

`$('body div.container div.panel>div.heading~div button').click();`

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to locate the button:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId'),
    innerDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document,
    button = innerDocument.getElementsByTageName('input')[0];
```

This will only work if the iframe origin from your server. This will find the first button, or `<input>`. If there's more than one `<input>` you could make a *for loop* and check for the 'button' type with `getAttribute('button');`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569012/simulate-a-click-on-a-element-using-javascript-jquery) will help you doing the click simulation.